# zsh / oh my zsh rendering and running a slightly mistaken command

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I've searched for this, but I haven't found a match. Even though I think it has to do with completion errors (of which there a few posts), my Zsh has a different and undesired outcome.

When I go 'up' to render the last command, and I edit it, and then hit enter, what it is sent it's not what was there right before running it. It's more productive if I show you the video->gif I just recorded:

[image]

This has happened since day one or as far as I can remember. It's always been a nuisance but I guess today is the day I'm ready to go the distance and fix it.

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
iTerm2 Build 3.2.9
zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0)
~/.zshrc -> plugins=(git zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-autosuggestions colored-man-pages z)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likekly due to a misunderstanding between iTerm2 and zsh regarding the width of the triangle symbol. Many previously single-width symbols became double wide (occupying two cells of the terminal emulator) in Unicode version 9.

Look around in iTerm2's setting, somewhere you'll find an option for the Unicode version (8 or 9), try all possible values here, most likely one of them will match zsh's assumption.

Alternatively, you can remove the triangle symbol from your prompt as a workaround.

Comment: You have a good point regarding the triangle symbol. Instead of totally erasing that from the prompt, one can tell _zsh_ that it has a width one character. Read about the `%G` in `man zshmisc` (section SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES).

Comment: @mpy Thanks for this addition! I didn't know about this (in fact, I'm not a zsh user myself).

Comment: @egmont It didn't work :( First I tried using the version 9, quit and reopen and still working bad. Then I removed the triangle from the prompt altogether, and the same thing. More ideas?